# layer-list dosen't display correctly below android m

Tags: android, layer-list

I wanna draw a cross like "x" and this is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:gravity="center">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="45"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="45">
      <shape>
        <corners android:radius="1px"/>
        <size
            android:height="2px"
            android:width="10px"/>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>
      </shape>
    </rotate>
  </item>

  <item android:gravity="center">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="45"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="45">
      <shape>
        <corners android:radius="1px"/>
        <size
            android:height="10px"
            android:width="2px"/>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>
      </shape>
    </rotate>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

It is ok on device running android m (api >= 22) but error on other devices (api < 22).

Is it the bug of android?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item
      android:bottom="10dp"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:left="10dp"
      android:right="10dp"
      android:top="10dp">
    <shape>
      <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
    </shape>
  </item>

  <item
      android:bottom="9dp"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:left="0dp"
      android:right="0dp"
      android:top="9dp">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="45"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%">
      <shape>
        <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@color/main_color_normal"/>
      </shape>
    </rotate>
  </item>

  <item
      android:bottom="0dp"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:left="9dp"
      android:right="9dp"
      android:top="0dp">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="45"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%">
      <shape>
        <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@color/main_color_normal"/>
      </shape>
    </rotate>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

It runs correctly.